# <<Hybris OCC>>While creating WsDtoDataList getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hi I am trying to define wsDtoDataobject of WsDto Type below is the code snipment for the same but getting error while build. "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid class name identifier java.util.List<de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.traininguserdetails.trainingUserDetailsWsDTO".

Can anyone help what am missing here

*commercewebservices-beans.xml

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.traininguserdetails.trainingUserDetailsDataListWsDTO">
<property name="trainingUserDetails" type="java.util.List&lt;de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.traininguserdetails.trainingUserDetailsWsDTO"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but I think you're missing the greater than symbol for the generics:

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.traininguserdetails.trainingUserDetailsDataListWsDTO">
    <property name="trainingUserDetails" type="java.util.List&lt;de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.traininguserdetails.trainingUserDetailsWsDTO&gt;"></property>
</bean>
```